# kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment at NavigationExtensionsKt

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

[image: Exception]

I copied the NavigationExtensions.kt extension file from the NavigationAdvancedSample and I get this exception:

Comment: Hi Amir, welcome to SO. Please post the actual text of your code and exception, using correct StackOverflow markdown (instead of images). Also have a look at  [**how to ask**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**how to create a minimum, reproducible example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for better results when using the site. Good luck!

Comment: You can do safe casting using `as?` operator.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

UPDATE: **make sure your menu item ids are the same as your navigation resource files ids**

also: if you're having a problem with ItemReselectedListener
Add null safety checks, your listener should be something like this:

```
setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener { item ->
        val newlySelectedItemTag = graphIdToTagMap[item.itemId]
        val selectedFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(newlySelectedItemTag)
                as NavHostFragment?
        val navController = selectedFragment?.navController
        // Pop the back stack to the start destination of the current navController graph
        navController?.popBackStack(
            navController.graph.startDestination, false
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 18):

In my case, I forgot to add android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment" in FragmentContainerView

Comment: This was the solution for me too. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I also faced this probelem, the solution is actually very simple.

**Make sure your menu item's id match the id of NAV_GRAPH not destinations.**

I was using the same ids for menu items and destinations, but in this case, menu item should have same id as of NAV_GRAPH.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue

Check that you have set your start destination and attached it to a fragment.
**in your nav graph set app:startDestination="@id/your fragment"**

this should solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

I manage to solve this problem.

In my case, I was calling `val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment` before `setContentView(binding.root)` so I change the order of the methods and everything was Ok.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this,
Actually, i set another layout for this activity in setcontentView,
When I set the original layout it worked.

Comment: Same lame thing for me

Answer (score 0):

So for me it was that inside my navigation graph file the id I declared on

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/my_id"
    app:startDestination="@id/container">
 ....
```

Was not the same name as the menu item

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/my_idd"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:title="@string/test_title" />
```

Changing the id to be the same for both solved the problem

Answer (score -1):

can you try with this?

```
val selectedFragment: NavHostFragment? = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(newlySelectedItemTag) as NavHostFragment
```

Comment: Won't work either cast it to a nullable type or use safe cast operator `as?`

Comment: then what will you do if selectedFragment is null?

Comment: wrap it with if else

Comment: it will throw the same exception if you try to do like this, it won't be able to cast to a non-null `NavHostFragment` type